# MMDB export and import

Tags: database, maxmind

I need to mapping the IP addresses into cities so I used maxmind geoip2 database. There's a problem that it only supports a few languages. I want to export the data from MMDB and translate the descriptions into several languages and import back to MMDB.

Is there any import/export tool for MMDB or any API that I can use for this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are tools for [exporting](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-perl/blob/master/bin/mmdb-dump-database) and [writing a new database](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Writer-perl). However, the whole process would likely be very time consuming. I would instead recommend using the included geoname_id to create a lookup table for the locations that you want to translate. You can use [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) as the data source for the localized names.